# Efficient within-column operation in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

Given a `pandas.DataFrame`, a list and a special value, I am looking for an elegant way to do:

> In a particular column of the df, every time the special value is encountered, check whether the preceding value in the series is in the list.

If **yes** return this preceding value.

If **no** go back one more value and check it.

A working implementation is:

```
ser = [1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 1, 4, 7, 2]
d = dict()
relevant =  [0,1]
df = pd.DataFrame([list(range(len(ser))), ser]).transpose()

for j in range(df.shape[0]):
    if df.iloc[j,1]==2:
        k=1
        while True:
            if df.iloc[j-k,1] in relevant:
                d[j] = df.iloc[j-k,1]
                break
            else:
                k+=1
```

This gives:

```
d
{1: 1, 3: 0, 8: 1}
```

I know I can use the [shift](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) function, but also when I use this I have a loop. I am wondering what is the best way to do this with elegance and if possible speed with no looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will need at least one loop, but you only need one.  What you are after is the last relevant value seen when you see the sentinel.  So this code keeps track of the last value seen while scanning for sentinels.

**Code:**

```
marker = 2
relevant = {0, 1}
ser = [1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 1, 4, 7, 2]
d = dict()
last_found = None
for i, val in enumerate(ser):
    if val == marker:
        if last_found is not None:
            d[i] = last_found
    elif val in relevant:
        last_found = val

print(d)
```

**Results:**

```
{8: 1, 1: 1, 3: 0}
```